# How can I document the structure of my code?

Tags: documentation

I've written a program and now I'm leaning towards writing documentation for it's source code in a separate file. Preferably I'd like to start off with the structure of the code (like how things are connected and what they transfer) on some sort of spreadsheet. Is there a standard format to do this in programming? An Application that is dedicated to this specific use or a filetype that is capable of doing so?

I've written this code for people who don't understand much about coding, so laying it out on a spreadsheet is inevitable, as they'll have to present it (and hence understand at least what is where). This is also the reason why I'd like to document it myself and not use a generator.The code itself is documented, but I'd like to put it into a separate file, to make it easier to understand instead of scrolling through it.

I'm thinking about using PowerPoint to create a structure based of the shapes it provides or XMind likewise. I'm not sure if there are better alternatives however and would like to know it before I start.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure, but it seems to me that the sort of software that would be standard for documenting code is not the sort of software that you need for your users. This may be a situation where you just have to do the best you can with the documentation tools your users will be comfortable with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now created a pdf using XMind and am exploring yEd and Gephi. Both don't run very well, but they get the job done.